# How can I get the specific character in string except the last one in Python?

Tags: python

I have several strings like below. How can I get the dot, except the decimal dot?

Please note: I need the digit after the decimal. I don't want to lose the decimal dot and the digit after that.

For example:

```
"8.2"

"88.2"

"888.2"

"8.888.2"

"8.888.888.2"
```

The output will be like this:

```
"8.2"

"88.2"

"888.2"

"8888.2"

"8888888.2"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dot except the decimal dot"? Do you mean "value except the decimal dot"?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the dot"? Are you hoping to remove all dots except for the last?

Comment: What about 8.222? Would that be 8222 or 8.222?

Comment: @saiedvaygani check regex solution.It should fulfill all your needs

Answer (score 13):

Use [`str.rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition). It will work correctly even when there isn't a `.` in the input, as evident below.

```
def fix_number(n):
    a, sep, b = n.rpartition(".")
    return a.replace(".", "") + sep + b

for case in ["8.2", "88.2", "888.2", "8.888.2", "8.888.888.2", "8"]:
    print(case, fix_number(case))
```

```
8.2 8.2
88.2 88.2
888.2 888.2
8.888.2 8888.2
8.888.888.2 8888888.2
8 8
```

Answer (score 9):

One way would be to split on the dots, then join together, treating the last one specially:

```
s = '8.888.888.2'
*whole, decimal = s.split('.')
res = ''.join(whole) + '.' + decimal  # gives: 8888888.2
```

You can use a similar method if you want to replace the thousands and/or decimal separators with another character:

```
s = '8.888.888.2'
*whole, decimal = s.split('.')
res = "'".join(whole) + ',' + decimal  # gives: 8'888'888,2
```

Answer (score 6):

Another idea is to call `str.replace()` with the [optional third argument `count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), which will replace only the first `count` occurrences of the character.

If we set `count` to be equal to `the number of "." minus one` we get the desired result:

```
words = ["8.2", "88.2", "888.2", "8.888.2", "8.888.888.2"]
new_words = []

for word in words:
    new_word = word.replace('.', '', word.count('.')-1)
    new_words.append(new_word)

print(new_words)
```

#### Output

```
['8.2', '88.2', '888.2', '8888.2', '8888888.2']
```

Answer (score 4):

I have broken down the code into simpler lines for better understanding and readability.

Try this:

```
words = ["8", "8.2", "88.2", "888.2", "8.888.2", "8.888.888.2"]
changed_word = []
for word in words:
    split_word = word.split(".")
    if len(split_word) > 2:
        before_decimal = "".join(split_word[0:len(split_word)-1])
        after_decimal = split_word[-1]
        final_word = before_decimal + "." + after_decimal
    else:
        final_word = word
    changed_word.append(final_word)

print(changed_word)
```

The output is:

```
['8', '8.2', '88.2', '888.2', '8888.2', '8888888.2']
```

The next step: try to optimise this code in fewer lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use re here.

```
\.(?=.*\.)
```

Just replace with `empty string`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/T9iX3B/1

```
import re

regex = r"\.(?=.*\.)"

test_str = ("\"8.2\"\n\n"
"\"88.2\"\n\n"
"\"888.2\"\n\n"
"\"8.888.2\"\n\n"
"\"8.888.888.2\" \n"
"8\n\n"
"the out put will be like this:\n\n"
" ")

subst = ""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
x = "8.888.888.22"
y = x.split(".")
z = "".join(y[:-1]) + "." + y[-1]
print(z)
# '8888888.22'
```

Comment: sometimes I don't have decimal. I just have for example 8

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the last occurrence of the dot(.). And then before that index, replace all the dots with an empty character, and add the remaining part of the string:

```
s = "8.888.888.2"
last = -1
for index, item in enumerate(s):
    if item == ".":
        last = max(index, last)
if last != -1:
    s = s[:last].replace(".", "") + s[last:]
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ["8", "8.2", "88.2", "888.2", "8.888.2", "8.888.888.2"]

for x in a:
    if '.' not in x:
        print(x)
        continue

    ridx = x.rindex('.')
    print(x[:ridx].replace('.', '') + x[ridx:])
```

Comment: What happens if there is no `.` in the input?

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73570389/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can imagine to solve your problem.

The first one is by parsing the string to another variable

```
example = 8888888.2
example = str(example) # In case that your input was in another type format
example_1 = example[-1:]
```

The output in this case would be "2".

For the second way, you can simple split the string into a list, and then you get only what you want:

```
example = 8888888.2
example = str(example)
example_2 = example.split('.') # Inside the parenthesis you can put the element you want to split the string, like a space, a comma, a dot
example_output = example[1]
```

In this case, the output was still the same "2" and in both cases you maintain your base variable just in case that you want the original input.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't answer OP's question at all – it doesn't have a string of the form `"8.888.888.2"`.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler function:

```
def remove_dot(word):
    dot_cnt = word.count('.')
    if dot_cnt <= 1:
        return word
    else:
        word = word.replace(".", "", dot_cnt - 1)
        return word

print(remove_dot("8.888.888.2"))
```

output : = `8888888.2`

Comment: That code, as posted, results in *"IndentationError: unexpected indent"*. Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73570583/edit) it? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now.)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution, without special functions
(inspired by the answer from [@AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx)).

```
def fix_number(n):
    return int( n.replace(".","") ) / ( 10 ** ('.' in n) )

for case in ["8.2", "88.2", "888.2", "8.888.2", "8.888.888.2", "8", ""8.888.888"]:
    print(case, fix_number(case))
```

The idea is that `'.' in n` returns 0 (False) if there are no dots, in which case we divide by 10^0 = 1. It returns 1 (True) if there are one or more dots, in which case we divide by 10.

```
8.2 8.2
88.2 88.2
888.2 888.2
8.888.2 8888.2
8.888.888.2 8888888.2
8 8.0
8.888.888 888888.8 <- not correct
```

As you can see, it returns a float even when there are no decimals. Not that the OP asked, but I think that's a nice feature :). However, it fails on the last test-case (which is not among the examples from the OP).

For this case we can replace the function with

```
def fix_number(n):
    return int( n.replace(".","") ) / ( 10 ** ('.' == n[-2]) )
```

but this fails on `8`.

Fixing that leads us to

```
def fix_number(n):
    return int( n.replace(".","") ) / ( 10 ** (n.rfind('.') == max(0,len(n)-2)) )
```

which outputs

```
8.2 8.2
88.2 88.2
888.2 888.2
8.888.2 8888.2
8.888.888.2 8888888.2
8 8.0
8.888.888 8888888.0
```

But at this point is gets a bit ridiculous :). Also the answer by [@AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx) is about 3.5 times faster.